# Call non parent activity's method from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

i have one login activity in which i am login using google. after successfully login i am moving to main screen. which has navigation drawer. now from the list of fragments, i want to sign out from google using one of fragment. how can i achieve this. below is my code:

LoginActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        initUi();
        setupListeners();


    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (MyApplication.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        MyApplication.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    }

    private void initUi(){
        llGoogle = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_login_llsignin_google);
    }

    private void setupListeners(){
        llGoogle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (session.isConnected()) {
                    getProfileInformation();
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (MyApplication.mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            MyApplication.mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            MyApplication.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

private void googlePlusLogin() {
    MyApplication.googlePlusLogin();
        resolveSignInError();
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>{

    public static Typeface app_medium;
    public static Typeface app_regular;
    public static Typeface app_bold;

    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();

    private static SharedPreferences Pref;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    // Google client to communicate with Google
    public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public boolean mIntentInProgress;
    public static boolean signedInUser;
    public static ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

        Pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


        checkFBKey();

        app_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/dax_regular.ttf");

        app_medium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/dax_medium.ttf");

        app_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/dax_bold.ttf");

    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }


    /**
     * set user login
     * */
//  public static void setUserFBLogin() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Editor edit_login_detail = Pref.edit();
//      edit_login_detail.putBoolean(GeneralClass.temp_iUserFaceBookBLOGIN,
//              true);
//      edit_login_detail.commit();
//  }



    public void checkFBKey() {

        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                // String something = new
                // String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }

    }

    public static void googlePlusLogin() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            signedInUser = true;
        }
    }

    public static void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
//          updateProfile(false);
        }
    }

    public static void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                            Log.e("LOGIN", "User access revoked!");
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!arg0.hasResolution()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // store mConnectionResult
            MyApplication.mConnectionResult = arg0;

            if (signedInUser) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("APPLICATION", "CONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


}
```

Now, i want to use googlePlusLogout() method in my fragment. how can i do that.?

Comment: Instead of keeping global credentials in `Activity` you should keep them in `Application`.

Comment: can you helping me with that? @SilentKiller

Comment: Code for google login and logout you need to implement in Application class just create getter setter for details.

Comment: @SilentKiller i implemented that. but now how can i move to another activity when google login successful. i mean after login, its call onConnected method of application class. so how can i use this method?

Comment: at onConnected() you can code like `fragmentManager.findFragmentById(layoutIDWhere you replace fragment);` and you can call fragment method too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement all your global credential and methods in `Application` class so you call it from any `Activity` or `Fragment` class.

Declare Set your LoginActivity as CurrentActivity in Application class and using `instanceOf` call loginSuccessful method of `LoginActivity` from Application at `onConnected()` method. and you can call logOut method from Fragment of an `Application` class.

Check Follow Example.

```
/**
 * @author AA-Sk
 * 
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Activity mCurrentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle mBundle) {
        Activity mActivity = getmCurrentActivity();
        if (mActivity != null) {
            if (mActivity instanceof LoginActivity) {
                LoginActivity mLoginActivity = (LoginActivity) mActivity;
                mLoginActivity.loginSuccessfull(mBundle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void googleLogout() {
    }

    public void setmCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity) {
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }

    public Activity getmCurrentActivity() {
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }

    /**
     * @author AA-Sk
     * 
     */
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setmCurrentActivity(LoginActivity.this);
        }

        private void loginSuccessfull(Bundle mBundle) {
            // Store Data from bundle and call another activity as user is successfully logged in.
        }

    }

    /**
     * @author AA-Sk
     * 
     */
    public class SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @author AA-Sk
     * 
     */
    public class logout extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }

        public logout() {
            ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).googleLogout();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i also implemented onConnected() method in Application class. thats what i am telling.

Comment: i added application class in question.. check it.

Comment: but i have activity which is using google login. not fragment.